# Parse Tree for Expression

Tags: parsing

I got the following question wrong on a test, but he didn't offer correct answers, and now the semester is over.

Does anyone know this?

I would love to know where I went wrong.

The question was to draw a *parse tree for* the following expression: `(a+b)*(c+d) - 4`

Answer (score 0):

I would draw it something like this:

```
        -
      /   \
    *      4
  /   \
  +     +
 / \   / \
a   b c   d
```

(Pardon my ASCII art skills)